# nested absolute element must be on top of bottom element

Tags: html, css

This is very simple code to ask the question.

1) Is there another way to make the nested 'inner' div be on top of the 'bottom' div,  the only way I can do it is to give the 'inner div a z-index integer value.

example it works with `z-index:90;` but not `z-index: auto;`

I am not able to alter the html/css of the 'outer' and 'bottom' div.

2) Is this issue because the order that the html is rendered?

```css
.outer {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: auto;
}
.inner {
  background: yellow;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 90px;
  z-index: 90;
  /* z-index: auto; why is it not working?*/
}
.bottom {
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">testing testing</div>
</div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because `auto` gives it the `z-index` of it's parent. Elements lower down in the DOM are placed over elements above them.

> ### [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)
>
> The box does not establish a new local stacking context. The stack level of the generated box in the current stacking context is the same as its parent's box.

For example:

```css
div{
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
}
div:after{
  position:absolute;
  content:"Test";
  top:100%;
  }
.upper{
  background:red;
  }
.lower{
  background:blue;
  }
```

```html
<div class="upper"></div>
<div class="lower"></div>
```

As you can see, the `.upper` is rendered under `.lower`, so the text from `.upper` is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

By using `z-index: auto;`, you give the element a z-index of the parent (0 if the parent has not set the value). If you have an element with a non-static position after the first one in the DOM (also with z-index: 0), the second one takes precedence over the first one. The browser always shows the last element on top, if they have the same z-index.

You can define a positive or negative z-index to alter the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

live the blue box in a `static` position or set `z-index:1;` to `.outer` div. whatever is inside `.outer` will be refering to `.outer` `z-index` value.

example without `z-index`, let `position:relative` work its way up :

```css
.outer {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  /* default value, no need to rewrite it del this >z-index: auto; */
}
.inner {
  background: yellow;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 90px;
  /* z-index: 1;1 would be enough if none set elsewhere in same area  */
}
.bottom {
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  /* position: relative; drop it  no need of z-index relative,absolute,fixed comes on top of static element */
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">testing testing</div>
</div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

If you want to keep `position:relative` for blue box, set `z-index` on `.outer` only

```css
.outer {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1; 
}
.inner {
  background: yellow;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 90px;
}
.bottom {
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">testing testing</div>
</div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```